# Installing Ubuntu with Windows XP

Tags: dual-boot, windows-xp

I would like to install Ubuntu on an old laptop and run in dual boot mode with Windows XP.
I cannot even get started.  I have created a partition on the HDD. I have tried loading Ubuntu as .iso file onto an R/W DVD and expanded the iso into separate files but it won't boot even when I press F12 and select the disk drive as the source for booting.  I have also tried the same thing with a usb stick. All that happens is that either the laptop boots into XP as normal or it just does nothing and has a black screen with a cursor flashing at the top left or sometimes 2 lines down.
Is it not possible to do what I want with Windows XP?  I see several other questions like this with no answers.

Comment: Yes. I used a method described in a help site which used the command window to format usb stick in fat32 mode then downloaded Ubuntu desktop .iso file, extracted it to the usb stick with winzip.  One of the files is called autorun which should be seen by the boot program but nothing happens.  I press F12 at start-up and select "removable device" from the list. The screen goes black with a dash cursor at top left- nothing happens. Tried transferring all the extracted files to the new disk partition and  double clicking on wubi.exe it worked for 2hrs then failed with error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install with USB stick you have to follow [this procedure](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) to make a bootable USB. Did you do something similar?

Edit: Why don't you try to use the method I linked, it is very well suited for users not expert in programming. It is a very straight forward procedure.

Comment: OK. I will try it but I am very wary of downloading programs for fear of viruses. The Pendrivelinux web site is confusing. It is difficult to see which download is the one I want and which is just an advertisement. Do I click on the blue label "Download UUI. Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.5"

Comment: I tried procedure and clicked on "Download UUI. Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.5". I chose "Run". After selecting ubuntu in the first box I clicked on "Browse" for the second box and all I got was a list of directories on my own PC not a list of .iso files to down load. I tried "Save" instead but the same thing happened.

Comment: Well did you download the .iso of the Ubuntu distribution you want before? The software is only supposed to put the .iso on the usb making it bootable, but it does not produce the .iso of Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes. I have downloaded ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso several times to a DVD and to a usb stick which has been formatted as fat32.  If I try to boot from the DVD I get an error message to say that a file isolinux.bin is missing. But it is there in a folder called isolinux. I expanded the iso file into its separate constituents to see if that helped but it did not. I could try copying isolinux.bin to the top level in case the boot program doesn't know how to find it.

Comment: AH. I think I get it.  The "Download UUI. Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.5". wants to know where I have put the Ubuntu .iso file which I am supposed to have downloaded previously.  This was not at all clear. I shall try that.

Comment: Yes exactly! Let us know the outcome

Comment: That worked. But I want to load Ubuntu into a new partition which I have already created on the hdd. When the installer gets to that point I select the appropriate partition but an error message says that it doesn't have a file system and I should select one from the partition tab (or something). Double clicking on the partition gives me a selection of file systems and I select ntfs but it still doesn't work.  When I quit a screen came up which looked like Ubuntu but was very slow. Was it working from the usb stick?

Comment: Linux run on ext4 and similar file system, not ntfs. However this would be out of the question you asked. In order to keep the structure of this web site it would be better to create other question for other matters.

Comment: Thanks for help I will ask a separate question. It seems one should not have extended discussions in comments but I can't see how else to have them. All very complicated.